# How to remove namespace from the output xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Below is my xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ms="http://www.test.com/schemas/test" 
xmlns:ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="ms ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<XMLResponse>           
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ms:ProductRS/ms:Product"/>
</XMLResponse>
</xsl:template>
<-- some templates here -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output i getting like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<XMLResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Product>-----</Product>
</XMLResponse>
```

I need to remove `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` from the xml output

Comment: What environment are you working in, and is the only reference to the xsi namespace in that XMLResponse line?

Comment: Why do you need to remove that namespace? Why do you want to?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I often find that the recipient system just cannot deal with namespace definitions in the XML. We have no control over the recipient system code. Sometimes the recipient can deal with expected namespaces, but not namespaces which were part of the original XSLT (e.g. xmlns:fn ... xpath-functions) but serve no purpose outside the XSLT.

Comment: @lafual See the accepted answer for how to omit namespaces.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To exclude a namespace then you should represent this way:-

`exclude-result-prefixes="ms ns xsi`"

Basically your stylesheet looks like this:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ms="http://www.test.com/schemas/test" 
xmlns:ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="ms ns xsi">
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the xsi prefix is not used anywhere in the stylesheet, and not wanted in the output, then just remove the declaration.

Comment: But on "copy-of" it's not work(
On each copy-of needs to supply copy-namespaces="no", but I try to find best approach...