# namespace issue in WSO2 ESB after XSLT transformation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an XML and transforming it using XSLT. But the result transformed xml file containing unnecessary namespces.

UPDATED

How to make the xslt not to have the xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" in the result xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute "exclude-result-prefixes" on xsl:stylesheet node and list the namespaces you want to exclude

Sample

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fo xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!

Jean-Michel is right, you must use exclude-result-prefixe="soapenv", thats works for me.

This question was aswered here:
[How to remove namespace from the output xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352412/how-to-remove-namespace-from-the-output-xml)

Comment: using  exclude-result-prefixe="soapenv" on the xslt is not working. Don't know what is the issue. Log mediator also printing the xml without namespaces but namespaces are coming when ESB sending the xml to end point. Did anybody came across this.

Comment: Which version of wso2esb are you using? Can you post your proxy code?