# How to remove soap namespace from root element

Tags: xslt

I am facing some issue in my xslt transformation. I want to remove extra namespace added in my result during xslt transformation.

here is the my source xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Root xmlns="http://www.abc123.org/xyz/ase" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Header>           
            <CreationDateTime>2019-05-08T06:34:04.2235068-05:0011</CreationDateTime>
            <BODID>51c336d1-8e6a-46211c-973f-a9ca6c8a33ce</BODID>
            <ReferenceID>9078111e00-9b82-46b3-a419-be80521b2a94</ReferenceID>
            <Success>false</Success>
         </Header>
         <Data>
            <ErrorMessage>
               <ID/>
               <Type>Invalid Data</Type>
               <Description>InvalidData</Description>
            </ErrorMessage>
         </Data>
      </Root>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

here is my xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.abc123.org/xyz/ase" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Header>           
            <CreationDateTime>2019-05-08T06:34:04.2235068-05:0011</CreationDateTime>
            <BODID>51c336d1-8e6a-46211c-973f-a9ca6c8a33ce</BODID>
            <ReferenceID>9078111e00-9b82-46b3-a419-be80521b2a94</ReferenceID>
            <Success>false</Success>
         </Header>
         <Data>
            <ErrorMessage>
               <ID/>
               <Type>Invalid Data</Type>
               <Description>InvalidData</Description>
            </ErrorMessage>
         </Data>
</Root>
```

Actual Output:

```
 <Root xmlns="http://www.abc123.org/xyz/ase" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <Header>           
            <CreationDateTime>2019-05-08T06:34:04.2235068-05:0011</CreationDateTime>
            <BODID>51c336d1-8e6a-46211c-973f-a9ca6c8a33ce</BODID>
            <ReferenceID>9078111e00-9b82-46b3-a419-be80521b2a94</ReferenceID>
            <Success>false</Success>
         </Header>
         <Data>
            <ErrorMessage>
               <ID/>
               <Type>Invalid Data</Type>
               <Description>InvalidData</Description>
            </ErrorMessage>
         </Data>
 </Root>
```

Here, I am getting extra namespace "xmlns:soapenv" that I need to remove.

Kindly suggest correction.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove namespace from the output xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352412/how-to-remove-namespace-from-the-output-xml)

Answer (score 2):

`xsl:copy` will copy any namespaces declared in the XML, even if the element itself does not use the namespace.

What you can do, is instead of using `xsl:copy` on elements, use `xsl:element` to create a new element, and copy across only the namespace declarations you need....

Try adding this template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() != 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']" priority="2">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[. != 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />  
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```